# Error when creating Facebook Canvas header through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm getting the error :

Param canvas_header[child_elements][0] must be a valid rich_media_photo_element id"

When using using the following (URL obscured):

```
curl \
-F 'canvas_header={ 
"name": "Test Header 20170924", 
"background_color": "000000", 
"child_elements": ["<photo id>"] 
 }' \
-F 'access_token=<token>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page id>/canvas_elements
```

I can't work out why the error is appearing. I've added a bunch of photos and used them for cover images in canvas, but this error is appearing for the header element and also the carousel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because there's such a paucity of references on the web in general.

For carousels, headers and footers, the photos must already be imported in as cover images to get a canvas photo ID and then added to the code above as a child element.